# Powershell script fails after adding TRY-CATCH logic

Tags: powershell

I have a script which I've been using for some time to transfer backups from a server to a FTP location.

It's been working without any hiccups for the last couple of months but recently the internet connection has been failing so I've tried to mitigate the impact of this on the script failing by adding a TRY-CATCH block with a retry logic.

The initial logic (that works) is:

```
$requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($backup_target_hss)
$chunk = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

$retryCount = 0

while( $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunk,0,$bufsize))
{
    $requestStream.write($chunk, 0, $bytesRead)
    $requestStream.Flush()
    "Flushed: " + $retryCount
}
$FileStream.Close()
$requestStream.Close()
```

and it continues to upload the file and works fine until the end.

But after adding a try-catch block it seems like it continuously skips sending the file through `$requestStream.Write` and `$requestStream.Flush()`:

```
$requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($backup_target_hss)
$chunk = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

$retryCount = 0

while( $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunk,0,$bufsize) -and $retryCount -ne 30 )
{
    try {
        $requestStream.write($chunk, 0, $bytesRead)
        $requestStream.Flush()
        "Flushed: " + $retryCount
        }
    catch [Exception] {
        Start-Sleep -s 10
        $retryCount += 1
        "Retry Count " + $retryCount

        echo $_.Exception|format-list -force
    }
}
$FileStream.Close()
$requestStream.Close()
```

I'm saying this because both scripts have the same number of prints of `"Flushed"` and all the messages are `"Flushed 0"`, but the `TRY-CATCH` version finishes in 5 seconds whereas the version without the error handling works fine.

Because both scripts print only "Flushed 0" it means that there is no jump into the `"CATCH"` blocks so the $retryCount variable doesn't get incremented, so `"TRY"` completes without any exceptions.

Any ideas why this might be and how I can solve this?

**UPDATE / CLARIFICATION**:

When I say the script fails, I mean that the outcome of the script version while using the TRY-CATCH is a single `1KB` file uploaded to my FTP, instead of the full 2.8GB file uploaded when I'm not using TRY-CATCH.

In both scenarios the script runs without throwing errors, but when using the TRY/CATCH it just finishes faster and does not actually do the entire "flush" of the file.

Comment: Is something throwing an error? What is your `$ErrorActionPreference` set to? It won't trigger a `Catch{}` block unless it encounters a terminating error, so you may want to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The script does not throw any error, so I have no leads to follow in my debugging. And regarding `$ErrorActionPreference`, I have no idea what it is. Is it a system-level variable?

Comment: If the script does not throw any errors then a Try/Catch block will not help at all. How do you know when it fails? You manually check afterwards and make sure the file is there? Can you pull file sizes or hashes after the upload to make sure the uploaded file is the same as the original? It sounds like you need a different way to accommodate for the internet issues.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician So, the script finishes with uploading a single file of 1KB in size, when using try/catch. In the other case, it's uploading the entire 2.8GB file. I'm sorry for the confusion, now I do realize that I didn't make this clear through my question. I'll update and correct.

Comment: What do you think the result of `$bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunk,0,$bufsize) -and $retryCount -ne 30` is? Hint: it's not what you think, at all. PowerShell isn't C!

Comment: I recommend using a dedicated ftp client [PS module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb) - no point in reinventing the wheel!